# Call constructor within another constructor

Tags: javascript

I found the following example in [Dojo: The Definitive Guide](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596516482/simulated_classes_and_inheritance.html):

```
function Shape(centerX, centerY, color)
{
  this.centerX = centerX;
  this.centerY = centerY;
  this.color = color;
};

function Circle(centerX, centerY, color, radius)
{

  this.base = Shape;
  this.base(centerX, centerY, color);
  this.radius = radius;
};

c = new Circle(10, 20, "blue", 2);
```

Please explain how this example works. I understand that when we call the constructor Circle, then `this` refers to the object being created, so it is clear for me why `c` object has `base` and `radius` properties, but how does it get `centerX`, `centerY`, `color`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you've assigned the `Shape` function to `this`, and then invoked it by doing `this.base()`.

So here, the `base` method is the `Shape` function, and when you do `obj.method()`, the value of `this` in `method` is set to the `obj`. Therefore the value of `this` in `Shape` is your new `Circle` object.

---

A more common approach is to use `.call()` instead of setting the function onto the object.

```
Shape.call(this, centerX, centerY, color);
```

This invokes the `Shape` function with its `this` value set to whatever you provided as the first argument. The rest of the arguments passed to `.call()` are just passed on as regular arguments to `Shape`.

---

I would guess they used `this.base = Shape` because there's some other use for `this.base` elsewhere in the code.

Comment: The `base` trick is for implementing something that looks like an object hierarchy without having to manipulate prototypes

Answer (score 2):

your `Circle` gets a new `base` property which resolves to the function named `Shape`:

```
this.base = Shape;
```

Then, that function is invoked and passed the `centerX`, `centerY`, and `color` parameters.  Since your `this` object never changes, `centerX` and friends are assigned to the same object which later gets the `radius` property:

```
this.base(centerX, centerY, color);
this.radius = radius;
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, functions are also objects. `Shape` is a function for adding methods and properties to `this`, which can be used by the `new` operator to make `Shape` objects. It can also be called by Circle to add methods and properties to the object being created by `Circle`.

Instead of assigning `base` you could do:

```
function Circle(centerX, centerY, color, radius)
{
  Shape.call(this, centerX, centerY, color);
  this.radius = radius;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with context of `this`, if I call window.dosomething() than `this` in `dosomething` is window. If I call `this.base` from the newly created c instance than `this` is .... the to be created c instance.

this.base happens to be Shape so when it's executed the `this` context is ... (you guessed; it's the to be created Circle).

The first line of Shape is:

```
this.centerX = centerX;
```

Now if you remember what `this` referred to you might now where the centerX property will be added.

This kind of inheritance doesn't use prototype so `console.log(c instanceof Shape)` is false and anyting on Shape's prototype isn't part of Circle.

For prototype inheritance you can read the following: [Prototypical inheritance - writing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711) (just the basics)